# Cast a viewController which segued modally in tabBar[1] in UINavigationController[1]

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift, uitabbarcontroller, segue

lets say i have a `UINavigationController` on a `TabBar.viewController[1]` like ->

```
let nav:UINavigationController = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[0] as UINavigationController
```

and `UITableViewController` at the `NavigationController.viewController[1]` like ->`

```
let mvc = nav.viewControllers[0] as UITableViewController
```

what if there is a modally segue in that table, how to cast that segued `viewController` to set something in that view without segueing

if any one can edit my question to be more clear that would be appreciated :)

*** UPDATE ***

i need to to do that without segueing cause maybe there is more than one ViewController will show up after that modally segue so i wanna set before doing any segue stuff (it's like setting delegates between tabBar viewControllers so we cast without moving to another ViewController in the TabBar)

maybe something like this

```
let nav = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1] as UINavigationController
let mvc = nav.viewControllers[1] as UITableViewController // but compiler crash `Array index out of range`
let something else to hold that ViewController from the nav
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply use the segue's `destinationViewController` property.

```
var customController =  segue.destinationViewController as YourControllerClass
customController.delegate = self
```

Comment: what if there is more than one ViewController after the segue and the same i want to get the delegate , it's like one view will show up modally and then another view will come after and when the second view dismissed it will add a rows into that tableView so i prefer to not use delegate and cast it do you have any idea to do this ?

Comment: No, the delegate pattern is what you should use. This is another question, so you should accept this answer first.

Comment: i dont think this is the answer but see my updated question and if you can help that would be cool , and thanks any way

Comment: Your crash is because you are trying to access the second view controller when there is only one. Use `topViewController` instaed.

Comment: i know but i wanted to get the view that is after the `topViewController` which i thought it would be the modally segued `viewController`

Comment: If a VC is modally segued, it is by definition not the second VC of the first VC's navigation controller. What you are trying to do is absurd. You should not have this complex view hierarchies even to edit the most complex objects. Follow the delegate pattern: have the presenting view controller get the finished message and take it from there up the hierarchy. That is all you need to know.

Comment: you know what, you maybe right for using delegates here but my question wasn't about delegates , but no problem i got that ,thanks for help any way

Comment: Thanks @Amro, right, you did not ask about delegates, but it is still a relevant and necessary part of the answer. Good luck!